# Solr with JQuery to build autocomplete

Tags: search, autocomplete, solr, solrj

I have set up solr and it works. I have tested it by indexing my MySQL db and running queries on it, trying facets and trying the term suggest component (which I wish to use with autocomplete).

I have recently walked through the reuters tutorial [here](http://wiki.github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/reuters-tutorial-step) and it worked on my local machine.

Now my solr instance is on: "http://[someurl]::8983/solr/" and the instance they are using in the 'reuters.js' file is 'http://example.solrstuff.org/solrjs/'. How do I change the code to point to my instance - when I just swap the urls the code in the example doesnt work anymore - no search results are displayed. Do I need to install SolrJS or something? What is going on here?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your tutorial link is broken.  Here is the correct url for the reuters tutorial: http://wiki.github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/reuters-tutorial

Comment: Can you try installing fiddler or some other HTTP traffic watcher and see where it goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a typo in your URL?  It looks like there are two colons in between the domain and the port number.  **http://[someurl]::8983/solr/** should be **http://[someurl]:8983/solr/**.  You can test by entering that URL into a browser on your test machine.  You should be able to get to the Solr admin page from there and do a query.  If you can't, it's a problem with your URL.